# how to fetch result from core data sorted by the object creation date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

sorry if the title is not clear, i'll explain:

I have a note creation page, after creating a note I'm saving the note using the model class (nsmanagedobject sub class).

I have another table view controller which I'm showing the notes, and I want the notes on the table view to be sorted by creation date, is there a key for that?

this is what i have now:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"body" ascending:YES];
```

the key here is the text of the note so its sorted by the abc, can you help me to sort it by date?

tnx

Comment: Do you have any such attribute like creationDate or anything on your entity ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no implicit creation date attribute for a managed object.  You can create an attribute, say *creationDate*, in your model and set it to `[NSDate date]` when you create an object.

Then you can simply sort on this attribute

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES];
```